# Basic MYSQL count selecting

Tags: mysql

I have a basic question about selecting counts:

If I have a table ContentTable with columns: id, property, text
And a VoteTable with columns: id, ContentTable_id, timestamp

And I want to select all rows from ContentTable where property = something, and also select into that row a column that is a count for how many rows in VoteTable have VoteTable.ContentTable_id = ContentTable.id, how would I structure this query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select col1, col2, (
 select count(*)
 from VoteTable vt 
 where vt.ContentTable_id = ct.id
) as count
from ContentTable ct
```